# How do I fix my Lenovo Laptop from black screen with cursor after boot up?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, lenovo-laptop

I can't figure out how to fix this because it does it like every time, I am currently using Windows 10 (Lenovo Laptop). I tried deleting apps I don't use, checking if Winlogon has different values, changing power plans, sfc /scannow, DISM, already checked for updates. Please help me because I don't know if my parent will buy me another laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You have changed many things including deleting apps you may not understand.

Best fix:  Use the Lenovo Recovery process and reinstall Windows.  If you cannot get to a startup screen in any way, you may need to get the Lenovo Recovery USB Key. Contact Lenovo Support and ask them the best way to reinstall Windows.

You may be able to get the recovery dialogue by repeatedly pressing F1 at startup.

This is better that buying a new laptop.